# find and replace exact matching hex on multiple lines

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0ZHO.png)

```
0070  41 67 65 6e 74 3a 20 4d 6f 7a 69 6c 6c 61 2f 34
0080  2e 30 20 28 63 6f 6d 70 61 74 69 62 6c 65 3b 20
```

I'm trying to find a way to find/match pattern

```
2f 34 2e 30 20 28 63 6f
```

and replace it with

```
2f 35 2e 30 20 28 68 63
```

Problem is this pattern can be broken up on two lines in many different ways e.g. `2f 34 2e 30 20` can be at end of first line then the rest of pattern on next line. I want to learn how so I can find a replace other (bigger) patterns as well.

This code only works if the pattern is fully contained on one line.

```
# replace hex equivalent of "/4.0 (co" with "/5.0 (hc" in hex field
sed 's/2f 34 2e 30 20 28 63 6f/2f 35 2e 30 20 28 68 63/g' <MPFADT$var.txt >>MPFADT$new.txt"
```

I have played with awk and sed but, to no avail. I have looked at perl examples as well.

I'm pretty sure I can get rid of the offset but, this requires merging which breaks formatting...

```
awk -F'  ' ' {print " "$2 > file} MPFADT$var.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Hex codes can be **printed** using multiple lines by the tool you use to produce the hex dump but the hex string contained in the original file is not "broken" into multiple lines. I mean if "2f 34 2e 30 20 28 63 6f" contained a new line somewhere... it would be a different hex sequence.

That said, I think you can just use sed:

```
$ sed 's/\x2f\x34\x2e\x30\x20\x28\x63\x6f/\x2f\x35\x2e\x30\x20\x28\x68\x63/' your_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way that doesn't care how long the string is you're trying to replace or how many lines it's split over:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    keys[NR] = $1
    sub(/^[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+/,"")
    buf = (NR>1 ? buf FS : "") $0
}
END {
    gsub(old,new,buf)
    for (i=1; i<length(buf); i+=(NF*3)) {
        print keys[++nr] "  " substr(buf,i,(NF*3)-1)
    }
}

$ awk -v old="2f 34 2e 30 20 28 63 6f" -v new="2f 35 2e 30 20 28 68 63" -f tst.awk file
0070  41 67 65 6e 74 3a 20 4d 6f 7a 69 6c 6c 61 2f 35
0080  2e 30 20 28 68 63 6d 70 61 74 69 62 6c 65 3b 20
```

It does read the whole file into memory though, idk if that's an issue for you or not. If it is you can define `buf` to be some max size and write code to rotate all of your input lines through it FIFO, doing the `gsub()` every time `buf` changes but that will be more complicated and less efficient and you then have to consider the 2nd `gsub()` potentially running on data that was modified by the 1st `gsub()` instead of on the original data.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it. First dump the file in *plain format* using `xxd` and that will suppress the addresses down the left side. Now delete all the linefeeds so that nothing can span multiple lines since your file is now one long line, then make your substitution with impunity, and rebuild with `xxd` again. It takes longer to describe than do!

```
xxd -p input.bin | tr -d '\n' | sed 's/2f342e302028636f/2f352e3020286863/g' | xxd -r -p - patched.bin
```

You better use **GNU sed** though as it has no limits on line length.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 'N;s/2f(\n....  | )34(\n....  | )2e(\n....  | )30(\n....  | )20(\n....  | )28(\n....  | )63(\n....  | )6f/2f\135\22e\330\420\528\668\763/;P;D' file
```

Keep a running window of two lines and pattern match. As the pattern may occur anywhere in the output allow for this by providing alternate patterns inbetween each pair of symbols.

N.B. You may have limited success because pagination may upset the apple cart.